Looking for a derivation of a difficult differential equation involving functions, inverse functions and a matrix
There are just too many different things going on here I am completely stumped with this derivation. if you can help much appreciated
$\mathbf{u}$ is a vector of length d and is not the zero vector. I have a function
f(u) = g-1(h-1(Ah(g(u))))
where g and h both take as input a vector of length d and output a vector of length d.  g and h are both bijective
A is a dxd matrix which is symmetrical, orthogonal and invertible.  It is a bijective linear operator.  It is given by A = Id - 2vvT
a paper I am looking at says
$$\frac{\partial f_{i}(\mathbf{u})}{\partial u_{j}} = \frac{A_{ij}.\frac{\partial h_{j}(g(\mathbf{u}))}{\partial v_{j}}.\frac{\partial g_{j}(\mathbf{u})}{\partial u_{j}}}{\frac{\partial h_{i}(h_{i}^{-1}(\mathbf{A}h(g(\mathbf{u}))))}{\partial v_{i}}.\frac{\partial g_{i}(g^{-1}(h^{-1}(\mathbf{A}h(g(\mathbf{u})))))}{\partial v_{i}}}$$
There are a few other bits and pieces but I don’t think they are relevant to the derivation.  If you are missing info then let me know and I will provide.  I think in their answer there may be no subscript i where it says $h_{i}^{-1}$ . I think it could be an error
I am trying to derive this to see if it is correct and understand the answer further.  If you can help that would be great
Many thanks again
Edit: my partial answer below but im not sure why the full answer given in the paper has partial derivatives with respect to u and also v?

you should give a link to the article.

yes ok it is the derivation of the equation found in appendix A here https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.12359

Ok I made a bit of progress. Trying to do a more simple version f(u) = g-1(Ag(u))
let v = Ag(u)
then by chain rule
$$\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{u})}{\partial u} = \frac{ \partial g^{-1}(v)}{ \partial v} . \frac{\partial v}{\partial  u} $$
$$ = \frac{1}{g’(g^{-1}(v))} . \frac{\partial v}{\partial  u}   $$
Substituting back for v (except the $ \partial v$ in g’)
$$ = \frac{1}{   \frac{\partial g      (g^{-1}(\mathbf{A}g(\mathbf{u}))}{\partial v}} . \frac{\partial \mathbf{A}g(\mathbf{u})}{\partial  u}   $$
For d = 2
$$ = \frac{1}{   \frac{\partial g      (g^{-1}(\mathbf{A}g(\mathbf{u}))}{\partial v}} . \frac{\partial }{\partial  u}   \begin{bmatrix} 
 A_{11}  A_{12} \\
 A_{21}  A_{22} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 g_{1}(\mathbf{u})  \\
 g_{2}(\mathbf{u})  \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$ = \frac{1}{   \frac{\partial g      (g^{-1}(\mathbf{A}g(\mathbf{u}))}{\partial v}} . \frac{\partial }{\partial  u}   \begin{bmatrix} 
 A_{11} g_{1}(\mathbf{u})  + A_{12} g_{2}(\mathbf{u})  \\
 A_{21} g_{1}(\mathbf{u})  + A_{22} g_{2}(\mathbf{u})  \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Where the top element is for $f_{1}(\mathbf{u})$ and bottom is for $f_{2}(\mathbf{u})$. So as an example for $\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial u_{2}}$
$$
\frac{\partial f_{1}(\mathbf{u})}{\partial u_{2}} = \frac{1}{   \frac{\partial g      (g^{-1}(\mathbf{A}g(\mathbf{u}))}{\partial v}} . \frac{\partial }{\partial  u_{2}}( A_{11} g_{1}(\mathbf{u})   + A_{12} g_{2}(\mathbf{u})  )  
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{   \frac{\partial g      (g^{-1}(\mathbf{A}g(\mathbf{u}))}{\partial v}} . \frac{A_{12}\partial g_{2}(\mathbf{u}) )  }{\partial  u_{2}}
$$
And that is not a million miles away from the requested answer.  I can now see roughly where all the components come from. Many thanks
